# <=> Operator behaves differently for x86 and arm

Tags: c++, clang, c++20

I have the following code which compiles correctly on [godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/YMGeGjeM6):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class A
{
    public:
    std::array<T,2> data_;
    constexpr friend auto operator<=>(const A<T>& a, const A<T>& b)
    {
        return  ( a.data_ <=> b.data_ );
    }
};

int main()
{
    using B = A<int>;

    auto a = B{0,0};
    auto b = B{1,1};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << (a.data_ <b.data_ );
    std::cout << (a<b);

}
```

The same program on Arm Mac, compiling with

```
clang++ spacetest.cpp -o spaceship -std=c++20
```

gives me the following error

```
spacetest.cpp:11:27: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::array<int, 2>' and 'const std::array<int, 2>')
        return  ( a.data_ <=> b.data_ );
```

The compiler version is

```
clang++ -v
Homebrew clang version 13.0.0
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
```

So, I dunno what I'm doing wrong here. Appreciate hints.

Comment: Considering that arm64 gcc has no issue with the code, we must assume it's a bug in that particular version of clang.

Comment: Better Godbolt link which shows ARM failing and x64 success: https://www.godbolt.org/z/3xaPofcqr

Comment: @MikeVine I've fixed that earlier by editing question.

Comment: @MarekR Maybe Tim [lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/616624)?

Comment: Thanks for the updated godbolt link. I didn't realize that there are more compilers than there are executioners. I'll go then ask the clang people.

Comment: The reason that @MikeVine's example fails with ARM clang and succeeds with x64 clang is that the former uses libstdc++ v8.2 and the latter uses libstdc++ v11.2 (because godbolt.org automatically passes `--gcc-toolchain=xxx` to clang, where `xxx` is chosen by the maintainers of godbolt.org). This might not be related to OP's problem.

Comment: @re-issue FYI Apple Clang and normal clang are not the same and behave differently. To the point that [compiler conformance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) listings even list them separately.

Comment: @Mgetz This it is. While this list mentions support for "<=>" in two entries, "Three-way comparison operator" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think @cpplearner his right with his comment. The `<=>`operator is supported in libstdc++ since version 10.1 (see table 1.9 here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020). The compilerexplorer uses the v8.2 toolchain for arm, so it's not yet supported. For x64, it uses v11.2, so it is supported.

You can check for the version by adding the `-v` compiler flag on the command line.